# Form elements with an ID

Tags: javascript, html, forms

It seems as though HTML `form` elements do not work correctly if they have an `id` attribute (`<form id="something" action="endpoint" method="POST">`).

What is another reliable way of selecting the correct `form` element on a page with several `form` elements?

I would prefer to use `getElementById` because `getElementsByTagName`, `getElementsByName`, etc. can return multiple results.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you say they don't work properly with an ID? They should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They **do work with an ID**, as long as that ID isn't used for **multiple** elements.

Given this:

```
<form id="myForm" method="POST">
</form>
```

You can do:

```
alert(document.getElementById("myForm").method);
```

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/xw3jc/**

Comment: yup, my mistake! accidentally disabled fields upon submission, which does not transmit the data.

Comment: @tau, why did you mark this answer as accepted, when you are saying that the problem was completely different?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela i did because this answer is correctly showed that i was wrong for thinking a `form` couldnt have an `id` attribute. if this isnt good stack overflow'ing, i guess this question should be closed then.

Answer (score 3):

ID will **always work**.

Make sure you have an unique ID, i.e. it appears only once in the whole page. If you have multiple IDs with similar name, although your HTML will work (albeit an invalid HTML that will NOT pass W3C validation), JavaScript won't.

Answer (score 1):

The `id` attribute value has to be unique and follow the rule (if not HTML5):

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

If it is HTML5, then the rules are softer: there has to be at least one character and no spaces.

If this is addressed, then the forms should work fine.